# value restriction case in F#

Tags: f#

I am puzzled as to why the 3rd function would not work :

```
   let generate1 = id
   let generate2 = let a = 1
                   id
   let generate3 = printfn "hi"
                   id
```

while the first 2 are fine, the last one spits out

```
error FS0030: Value restriction. The value 'generate3' has been inferred to have generic type
    val generate3 : ('_a -> '_a)    
Either make the arguments to 'generate3' explicit or, if you do not intend for it to be generic, add a type annotation.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I won't attempt to [explain value restriction](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mulambda/archive/2010/05/01/value-restriction-in-f.aspx), but I will attempt to sort out the semantic differences between these three values.

`generate1` is just an alias for `id`, so we're good there.

`generate3` does some computations before returning `id`, hitting value restriction.

Then why doesn't `generate2` hit value restriction like `generate3`? Because the compiler can see that `let x = 1 in id` is semantically equivalent to just `id`: `1` is a constant expression and `x` not used in the body of the `let ... in ...` expression, so the compiler can and does throw them away. On-the-other-hand, if you replace `1` with a potential side-effect like `sin 2.3` (`sin` is pure, but the compiler can't prove it), then the compiler can't safely reduce the expression, thus hitting value restriction as with `generate3`.

Comment: Interesting example with sin. the link between value restriction and provable side-effect free is not trivial to me. I would not have put such an error message methink.